# inotify script runs twice?

Tags: inotify, inotifywait, inotify-tools

I'm using [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) (`inotifywait`) on CentOS 7 to execute a php script on every file creation.

When I run the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR="/path/to/some/dir"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
    php /path/to/myscript.php ${NEWFILE}
done
```

I can see there are 2 processes:

```
# ps -x | grep mybash.sh
    27723 pts/4    S+     0:00 /bin/sh /path/to/mybash.sh
    27725 pts/4    S+     0:00 /bin/sh /path/to/mybash.sh
    28031 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mybash.sh
```

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps variable names are specified by POSIX as used for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Answer (score 0):

A pipeline splits into multiple processes. Thus, you have the parent script, plus the separate subshell running the `while read` loop.

If you don't want that, use the process substitution syntax available in bash or ksh instead (note that the shebang below is no longer `#!/bin/sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
monitordir=/path/to/some/dir

while read -r newfile; do
    php /path/to/myscript.php "$newfile"
done < <(inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "$monitordir")
```