# where does the 2nd process come from

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Put the following code into a shell script e.g. x.sh and chmod +x x.sh

> ./x.sh

what I expect is there is only one line, while actually, I got 2 lines:

```
tmp $ ./x.sh
52140 ttys003    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./x.sh
52142 ttys003    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./x.sh
```

My question is where does the 52142 come from?

```
#!/bin/sh
myself=$(basename $0)
running=$(ps -A | grep "$myself" |grep -v grep)
echo "${running}"
```

Note: this is on MacOS 10.12

Updated the question with new experiment:

```
#!/bin/sh
myself=$(basename $0)
running=$(ps -fe | grep $myself |grep -v grep)

echo ==== '$(ps -fe | grep "$myself" |grep -v grep)' ====
echo "${running}"
echo 

running=$(ps -fe | cat)
echo ==== '$(ps -fe | cat) |grep $myself' ====
echo "${running}"|grep $myself
echo 

running=$(ps -fe)
echo ==== '$(ps -fe) |grep $myself' ====
echo "${running}" |grep $myself
```

The output on MacOS 10.12 is:

```
==== $(ps -fe | grep "$myself" |grep -v grep) ====
  501 59912 81738   0  9:01AM ttys003    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./x.sh
  501 59914 59912   0  9:01AM ttys003    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./x.sh

==== $(ps -fe | cat) |grep $myself ====
  501 59912 81738   0  9:01AM ttys003    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./x.sh
  501 59918 59912   0  9:01AM ttys003    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./x.sh

==== $(ps -fe) |grep $myself ====
  501 59912 81738   0  9:01AM ttys003    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./x.sh
```

From above, it seems the subshell is also related to pipe.

Comment: Pipes are usually implemented by forking. Also, $() is **command** substitution -- does that sound like it may create processes?

Comment: it generates an infinite nesting of calling itself. Isn't it?

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti Why? Where?

Comment: Jens, sorry, the way I see it is that you have a script X calling itself in an infinite way

Comment: @Jens, you should be right, great thanks

Comment: Also the same root cause as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040685/inotify-script-runs-twice

Answer (score 4):

`$(command)` is command substitution. The `command` was executed in a subshell.

A subshell is a child process (fork) of your original shell (or shell script), if you check with `ps`, the file name part is same as your original(parent) shell script.

You can verify it by changing your `x.sh` into:

```
echo "$(ps -fe --forest>foo.txt)"
```

With `--forest` ps will output a tree structure with sub processes. Open the `foo.txt` search `x.sh`, you will see the tree structure.

If I run here on my machine, I get:

```
kent     20866   707  0 15:55     \_ urxvt 
kent     20867 20866  0 15:55         \_ zsh
kent     21457 20867  0 15:56             \_ sh ./x.sh
kent     21459 21457  0 15:56                 \_ sh ./x.sh #subshell
kent     21460 21459  0 15:56                     \_ ps -fe --forest
```

If we add one more layer, change your script to:

```
(
echo "$(ps -fe --forest>foo.txt)"
)
```

Now our `x.sh` will create two nested subshells, if I run and check my `foo.txt`:

```
... 25882 27657  0 16:05 ...  \_ -zsh
... 31027 25882  0 16:16 ...      \_ sh ./x.sh
... 31028 31027  0 16:16 ...          \_ sh ./x.sh #subshell1
... 31029 31028  0 16:16 ...              \_ sh ./x.sh #subshell2
... 31031 31029  0 16:16 ...                  \_ ps -fe --forest
```

The `$PPID` show it too.

Comment: `ps T --forest` or `ps U $USER --forest`would make the search easier.

Comment: Great thanks Kent. The subshell listed seems also related to the pipe. Without the pipe in $(), the subshell doesn't shown. I couldn't attach code in comment and will update in the question. ps On MacOS, the --forest is not supported